How to find the minimum of this function using CVX optimizer
I am new in optimization world and trying to optimize a problem using CVX. This is how I define my objective:
cvx_begin
    variables x1 x2 % Define the optimization variables
    expression obj % Define the objective function expression
    
    % Define the objective function
    obj = x1 + x2 + 1/log2(1 + x1/(1 + x2)) + 1/log2(1 + x2/(1 + x1));
    
    % Minimize the objective function
    minimize(obj)
    
cvx_end

But this error shows up:
Disciplined convex programming error:
Cannot perform the operation: {real affine} ./ {real affine}
Error in  ./  (line 19)
z = times( x, y, './' );
Error in  *  (line 36)
z = feval( oper, x, y );
Error in  /  (line 15)
z = mtimes( x, y, 'rdivide' );
Error in test (line 7)
obj = x1 + x2 + 1/log2(1 + x1/(1 + x2)) + 1/log2(1 + x2/(1 + x1));
I tried using inv_pos like
% Start the CVX optimization
cvx_begin
    variables x1 x2 % Define the optimization variables
    expression obj % Define the objective function expression
    
    % Reformulate the objective function
    obj = x1 + x2 + inv_pos(log(2) * log(1 + x1/(1 + x2))) + inv_pos(log(2) * log(1 + x2/(1 + x1)));
    
    % Minimize the objective function
    minimize(obj)
    
cvx_end


but the problem consists.

The error you are encountering in CVX stems from the fact that CVX enforces 'disciplined convex programming (DCP)' rules. Operations like the division between optimization variables x1/(1+x2) violate these rules if CVX does not recognize them as convex.
You need to reformulate the terms 1/log2(1 + x1/(1 + x2)) and 1/log2(1 + x2/(1 + x1)) into forms that CVX accepts as convex. You might want to use a 'convex approximation' of these terms.
My approach will likely depend on the exact form of the objective function you are aiming to optimize.
If you were to reform your problem using the log-sum-exp function which is considered convex can be used as an approximation for log-based expressions.
$$\text{log-sum-exp}(x) = \log \left( \sum_i e^{x_i} \right)$$

(That equation is LaTeX based)
CVX also provides the rel_entr(x, y) function which computes x log (x/y) which can be used to rewrite the log terms into a convex form.
cvx_begin
    variables x1 x2
    expression obj
    
    % Reformulate the objective using relative entropy (convex reformulation of log)
    obj = x1 + x2 + rel_entr(1, 1 + x1/(1 + x2)) / log(2) + rel_entr(1, 1 + x2/(1 + x1)) / log(2);
    
    % Minimize the objective
    minimize(obj)
    
cvx_end

If this approach does not work, you may need to simplify or linearize certain parts of your function. Other optimization methods that you can use include gradient-based optimization if your objective is non-convex.
